# Magento import products with existing image

Tags: magento

I am developing a Magento site hosted on Godaddy. I've already manually added some products. Right now, I am trying to import a lot more product which are using the same images.

Let me give you an example. Say I manually added a product with image A. In the csv file I exported, image path is m/u/mud3021.png. Right now I am trying to import product B and C with the same image, but when I put the same image path under the corresponding column, the image doesn't show up in the product page. I mean, everything else shows up but the image. Please help me get this through.

I also tried this path /public_html/media/catalog/product/m/u/mud3021.png because it's the path shows on FileZilla. But it doesn't work either.

Comment: I think I can lead you in the right direction but you'll probably have to do more research to import multiple image. Importing an image path through the standard CSV product import will not work. If I remember correctly, images you want to import must be placed in a separate folder (I think /media/import) and then you would use the Data-Profiles to create an profile to import your images. To do this, you create a new spread sheet, first have your SKU in your first column  and then include the following image fields you want to import (image, smallimage, thumb, etc.) and the correct file names.

Comment: Have you tried Magmi http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page ?

Answer (score 2):

Your using the bad path to the media folder.
You should use magento getBaseUrl like below:

```
$mediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . "catalog/product/";
```

and then you just add your image path to the media url in order to view the image like below:

...
let's say that $imgPath = m/u/mud3021.png ;

```
$imgUrl .= $mediaUrl.$imgPath ;
```

So you will successfully show your image in product page :)